# Linear Algebra - Test addition closure of a vector space

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, vectors, axioms

I am having trouble wrapping my head around proving the axiom: "vector plus another vector within a set exists in the set". Mainly, I am not sure how to go about proving it with the given polynomial.

V = {[x,y,z] such that 3x-2y+z=0}

My initial thought was that since you are proving a polynomial with the trivial solution, then V *must* be a vector space. What can I do to prove whether this is a vector space? Thank you.

Comment: A vector space is closed under addition.  The sum of two polynomials of equal degree form a polynomial of the same degree.  This would suggest that $p_n(x)$ (polynomials of degree n) meets criteria defining a vector space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpler proof:

The equation $3x-2y+z=0$ is the equation of a plane that passes through the origin, that is a subspace of dimension $2$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ .

So the set of vectors $[x,y,z]$ that satisfies such equation are the vectors of the plane, and are elements of a vector space.

If you want to prove directly the addition closure take two vectors 
$$
\vec x=[x,y,z] \quad \mbox{with} \quad 3x-2y+z=0 
$$
and

$$
\vec v= [u,v,w] \quad \mbox{with} \quad 3u-2v+w=0 
$$

and note that:
$$
 \vec x +\vec v=[x+u,y+v,z+w]
$$
so that:
$$
3(x+u)-2(y+v)+(z+w)=3x-2y+z+3u-2v+w=0+0=0
$$

Comment: Thanks! Very straightforward